# Short summary of an Javascript async functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Im new to programming and am confused about the async function present in the javascript language. Why do you use it, and how?

Short demo:

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An async function is a function declared with the async keyword. Async functions are instances of the AsyncFunction constructor, and the await keyword is permitted within them. The async and await keywords enable asynchronous, promise-based behavior to be written in a cleaner style, avoiding the need to explicitly configure promise chains.

Answer (score 0):

If we start from first principles, it will be helpful to understand what "asynchronous" means:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/asynchronous

> Asynchronous software design expands upon the concept by building code that allows a program to ask that a task be performed alongside the original task (or tasks), without stopping to wait for the task to complete.

And have a good understanding of the different approaches to handle asynchronicity like [callbacks functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) and [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

If you have those, @Jeffrey's answer is a solid explanation of what the `async`-`await` syntax is – a nicer way to express what promises do. For further reading you can see [Making asynchronous programming easier with async and await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).